# Start game if anything but a UI Button is touched

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm building an iOS game and I had the game set up to start whenever the user first touched the screen.  This was working out perfectly fine for testing until I added menu buttons as an overlay that would disappear when the game starts.  Obviously I can no longer just check for user input, because the game now starts even if I tap a UI button. 

I tried adding an invisible UI panel with a box collider behind my UI buttons with an OnPointerDown that would start the game, but for some reason it was acting very inconsistent and would sometime require 5+ taps to start the game. It also wouldn't start if you tapped on the player because it would hit his collider instead.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you look at: `EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject()`  This will return true if it is over a UI GameObject.

Comment: I did but I couldn't figure out how to return what game object the pointer was over.  I have a background game object in the scene so there's always a game object.  Is there a way I can get the tag of the game object?

Comment: there isn't that I know of but if that Background object isn't on the UI it should not return true.  You can look up a video by Unity3D college where he shows this being used.

Comment: Why dont you just check for a single touch, anywhere on the screen? It seems to me that should be enough to solve the issue.

Comment: @Eddge Thanks I'll try to find the video. @ bolkay A single touch anywhere on the screen is how I was initially starting the game, but if the user taps the mute button, for instance, it is still starting the game

Comment: @Eddge This didn't seen to work.  Even when there are no objects in my game scene on the UI layer EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject() still returns true on every click.  I don't understand

Comment: @dulongj does your scene have an EventSystem in it?

Comment: @Eddge Yes it does. Disabling it causes the click to return false, but when it's enabled the click returns true even when no objects are on the UI layer.